# Generate files in different folders using Open API generator

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using openapi-generator to generate the POJOs from a JsonSchema.
In my pom.xml, I have specified the

`<output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi</output>`  `<modelPackage>com.test.generated.model</modelPackage>`

This generates all the files in :

`generated-sources/openapi/src/main/java/com.test.generated.model`

I have conflicting class names based on different schema and this is causing error.

Is there a way to separate autogeneration for each schema in a separate folder ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have multiple openapi schema generation into a single package. Keeping multiple execution for each open schema (by giving different packages) may solve it. This is a basic way that I use for such purposes:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
<artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.3.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>gen1</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <inputSpec>${basedir}/../openapi/openapi-spec1.yml</inputSpec>
            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
            <library>spring-boot</library>
            <apiPackage>${project.groupId}.spec1.api</apiPackage>
            <modelPackage>${project.groupId}.spec1.api.model</modelPackage>
            <configOptions>
                <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
            </configOptions>
            <configHelp>false</configHelp>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>gen2</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <inputSpec>${basedir}/../openapi/openapi-spec2.yml</inputSpec>
            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
            <library>spring-boot</library>
            <apiPackage>${project.groupId}.spec2.api</apiPackage>
            <modelPackage>${project.groupId}.spec2.api.model</modelPackage>
            <configOptions>
                <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
            </configOptions>
            <configHelp>false</configHelp>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>gen3</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <inputSpec>${basedir}/../openapi/openapi-spec3.yml</inputSpec>
            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
            <library>spring-boot</library>
            <apiPackage>${project.groupId}.spec3.api</apiPackage>
            <modelPackage>${project.groupId}.spec3.api.model</modelPackage>
            <configOptions>
                <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
            </configOptions>
            <configHelp>false</configHelp>
        </configuration>
    </execution>                           
</executions>
</plugin>
```